# Nested Assemblies

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0

I have a code library(Dll_A) that calls another call code library(DLL_B)

DLL_A will be distributed to other applications for use. When I try to use Dll_A it is saying I must have DLL_B in the reference as well.

If there a way to roll up everything into DLL_A and only have to import that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly. It works on executables and DLLs alike and comes with several options for controlling the processing and format of the output. See the accompanying documentation for details."

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks. This makes thing easier.